# About sequences with zeros

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ be a real sequence. I want to characterize $(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ according to the number of zeros in its values. We have two cases: This number is finite or infinite.

My **question** is: Can we find a **list** of mathematical statements of the form:

$(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ has a finite number of zeros if and only if some case $(P)$ is verified

or

$(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ has an infinite number of zeros if and only if some case $(P)$ is not verified

Comment: $(x_n)$ has an infinite number of $0$ $\iff$ there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ s.t. $x_{n_k}=0$ for all $k$.

Comment: The existence of such a list might solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) .